# Trimming an export area in Fireworks

Tags: adobe-fireworks

Is it possible to roughly select an area (with the Export area tool) around an image you are working on and have the bounding box automatically shrink to fit it?

[image]

to

[image]

I have to do this a *lot* and manually drawing the bounding box is v. fiddly, and it is easy to click outside the handles and have to start again!

I usually can't use 'trim' on the whole page because there will be other elements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are using the wrong tool. The tool name "Export Area" means you select an area of the image and ask Fireworks to export that whole area out.

If you want to use native tool, that will be export the selected object by using the slice tool.

This is all you need to do

1. First, select the object.
2. Right click to get the context menu
3. Choose "Insert Rectangle Slice"
4. Export the image

Sreenshot - http://cl.ly/image/0Q3b0k0Y2k2c

Comment: OK cool, that works  - and if I use 'Image Preview' I can still refine the export format as well.

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer, but to achieve the same result I use the [Export Selection](http://johndunning.com/fireworks/about/ExportSelection) extension. that lets you select something and export with white or transparent backgrounds. Before that I used to copy & paste into a new document with the [To New Document](http://www.senocular.com/fireworks/extensions/?entry=552) extension

Comment: Seems like that might be the best solution, cheers! I find it a bit odd that FW doesn't do it natively.